# Why can't I delete a property in a map function, in CouchDB?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I've got a `view` and a `map` function, in `CouchDB`. I'm simply iterating over some values in an array, an emitting them individually. I'd like to exclude a property of the documents that I am emitting, though. I was hoping to just call `delete` on it, but that doesn't appear to be doing anything. The value is still emitted with the property. Is this a limitation in order to keep indexing fast? My map function looks like this:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == 'user' && doc.spaces) {
    doc.spaces.forEach(function (space) {
      if (space.tokens) {
        space.tokens.forEach(function (token) {
          emit(token.token, space);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Where I emit `space`, I'd like to delete the `tokens` property of it, before emitting. I don't want to expose other tokens in this data. So, I modified to code to look like this, with no luck. It still emits the full document, with tokens intact:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == 'user' && doc.spaces) {
    doc.spaces.forEach(function (space) {
      if (space.tokens) {
        var tokens = space.tokens;
        delete space.tokens;
        tokens.forEach(function (token) {
          emit(token.token, space);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been bitten by this problem as well.

We worked around it by creating a new object and emitting that instead:

```
emit(token.token, {
  name :  space.name,
  id : space.id
  etc : etc
}
```

We found that was the best way anyway as most of the time there was no need to emit complete (child) documents and only what was required.

Comment: That is due to "sealing": CouchDB JavaScript query server uses this SpiderMonkey feature to make documents unchangeable while he is processed by map functions. This prevents accidentally document modification and his processing in such state by other map functions.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, the reference to "sealing" an object is about the ES5 feature ([Object.seal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)) that SpiderMonkey implements.

Comment: i even tried setting it to a new variable, and it appears to remain sealed. `var newobject = doc;`

Comment: The reason that doesn't work is because newObject is just another reference to the same doc object. newObject points to the same "sealed" object. You will need to create a new object as in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

It happened the same trouble for me, now. And I was search the topic. But unfortunately, the other answer was not useful for me. Because, CouchDB is not SQL, documents has a different properties. Therefore I cannot `emit` with a specific properties.

After thinking, I hit on an idea for the problem. It is there:

```
function( doc )
{
  // Remove a `seal` in the doc using a deep-copy technique.
  var tmp = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( doc ) );

  // We can `delete` a property as we like!
  delete tmp._rev;

  // Emit `tmp`.
  emit( null, tmp );
}
```